# android listview data not refresh data come from server

Tags: java, android, listview

i have a layout which have edit_text button and list_view i enter text in edit text and send it with button when i click button data will show in list_view problem is that data show only when i click on back button and again open list_view then data show . i have issue in list_view refresh i want when i send data list_view automaticaly updated and show me a data here is the code of list_view.

```
protected void showList() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            //String sender_email = c.getString(TAG_SENDER_EMAIL);
           // String reciver_email = c.getString(TAG_RECIVER_EMAIL);
            String data = c.getString(TAG_DATA);
            //       String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
           //  e1.setText(reciver_email);

            HashMap<String, String> user_data = new HashMap<String, String>();

            //           persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            user_data.put(TAG_DATA, data);
            //      users.put(TAG_EMAIL,email);

            personList.add(user_data);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                DataSendActivity.this, personList, R.layout.layout_chat,
                new String[]{TAG_DATA},
                new int[]{R.id.data}

        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' after you fill your list ?

Comment: no how to use it ?? i am new in android please tell me

Answer (score 0):

use the code bellow:

```
protected void showList() {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            DataSendActivity.this, personList, R.layout.layout_chat,
            new String[]{TAG_DATA},
            new int[]{R.id.data}

    );

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
    peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

    for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
        //String sender_email = c.getString(TAG_SENDER_EMAIL);
       // String reciver_email = c.getString(TAG_RECIVER_EMAIL);
        String data = c.getString(TAG_DATA);
        //       String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
       //  e1.setText(reciver_email);

        HashMap<String, String> user_data = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //           persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
        user_data.put(TAG_DATA, data);
        //      users.put(TAG_EMAIL,email);

        personList.add(user_data);
    }

 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: why? what is the problem? is there any exception?